# Enviar elemento anterior al actual

Tags: javascript, html

la pregunta es muy sencilla, si bien es cierto que puedo enviar como parámetro las propiedades del elemento (HTML) actual a una función de javascript con "this", en este caso enviar el Id, cómo puedo hacer para enviar las propiedades del elemento del DOM anterior a este

Ejemplo, como lo tengo:

```
<div id="Este_si">Necesito enviar este elemento</div><button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" id ="test" onclick="incrementar(this.id);">+</button>
```

Como lo necesito:

```
<div id="Este si">Necesito enviar este elemento</div><button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" id ="test" onclick="incrementar(div.id);">+</button>
```

Si tuviera sólo el botón, envío el id de ese botón con "this" correcto?, como tengo un div y un botón, quiero enviar el id del div, haciendo click en el botón

algo así es la idea

Gracias

Comment: Lo que buscas es conseguir el contenido actual del `div` con Javascript?

Comment: Si tuviera sólo el botón, envío el id de ese botón con "this" correcto?, como tengo un div y un botón, quiero enviar el id del div, haciendo click en el botón

Comment: Qué es lo que quieres lograr? Tipo, hacer esto con cuál objetivo final?

Comment: necesito enviar el id de un input haciendo click en el botón, el cual se encuentra justo al lado

Answer (score 1):

Lo que planeas tendría más orden y facilidad de implementación si:

- Recuperas en una variable el botón
- Recuperas en una variable el div del cual quieres enviar su ID
- Das un listener al evento click del botón y recuperas la propiedad ID del div deseado

Código

```
let boton = document.getElementById("su-id");
let div = document.getElementById("su-id");
```

Ahora el listener

```
boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log(div.id);
});
```